# Convert list to dictionary in json file in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm working on a json file in python like this:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60de048cd7905488bbe0e511"
  },
  "item_name": "STOCKHOLM",
  "item_type": "Sofa",
  "item_id": "302.450.44",
  "item_detail": [
    "3paxsofa",
    "seglora"
  ],
  "item_price": "18990",
  "item_count": "35",
  "item_size": {
    "width:": "211 cm",
    "depth:": "88 cm",
    "height:": "80 cm",
    "heigth2:": "14 cm",
    "height3:": "72 cm",
    "depth2:": "158 cm",
    "depth3:": "59 cm",
    "height4:": "43 cm",
    "no:": "3 "
  },
  "item_collapsepk": {
    "product_id: ": "302.450.44",
    "pack: ": "1",
    "depth: ": "216 cm",
    "width: ": "92 cm",
    "height: ": "60 cm",
    "total_weight: ": "71.26 kg",
    "net_weight: ": "56.64 kg",
    "pack_per: ": "1176.0 L"
  },
  "maintenance": [
    "avoid sunset ",
    "clear with wet towel"
  ],
  "item_good": [
    "natural leather ",
    "softer leathwe ",
    "depper color and longer lifespan",
    "Niels Gammelgaard"
  ],
  "item_env": {}
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60de048fd7905488bbe0e513"
  },
  "item_name": "HEMLINGBY",
  "item_type": "sofa",
  "item_id": "704.343.68",
  "item_detail": [
    "2pax sofa",
    "knisa"
  ],
  "item_price": "899",
  "item_count": "2627",
  "item_size": {
    "width:": "145 cm",
    "depth:": "71.5 cm",
    "height:": "71.5 cm",
    "heigth2:": "14.5 cm",
    "height3:": "61 cm",
    "depth2:": "137 cm",
    "depth3:": "54 cm",
    "height4:": "42 cm"
  },
  "item_collapsepk": {
    "product_id: ": "704.343.68",
    "pack: ": "1",
    "depth: ": "137 cm",
    "width: ": "73 cm",
    "height: ": "32 cm",
    "total_weight: ": "34.32 kg",
    "net_weight: ": "29.86 kg",
    "pack_per: ": "320.0 L"
  },
  "maintenance": [
    "no bleach",
    "no dry"
  ],
  "item_good": [
    "fixed"
  ],
  "item_env": {}
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60de15b556f3d120e64db051"
  },
  "item_name": "ANGERSBY",
  "item_type": "梳化",
  "item_id": "804.571.18",
  "item_detail": [
    "2paxsofa",
    "knisa "
  ],
  "item_price": "1690",
  "item_count": "842",
  "item_size": {
    "width:": "137 cm",
    "depth:": "84 cm",
    "width1:": "120 cm",
    "depth2:": "49 cm",
    "heigth2:": "46 cm"
  },
  "item_collapsepk": {
    "product_id: ": "804.571.18",
    "pack: ": "1",
    "depth: ": "87 cm",
    "width: ": "62 cm",
    "height: ": "47 cm",
    "total_weight: ": "28.00 kg",
    "net_weight: ": "26.28 kg",
    "pack_per: ": "253.5 L"
  },
  "maintenance": [
    "no bleach",
    "no dry",
    "咕套",
    "fixed",
    "40 degree with noral mode"
  ],
  "item_good": null,
  "item_env": [
    "loner lifespan",
    "60%polyester",
    "40%rubber"
  ]
 }
]
```

And I want change all the list in the json file to a dictionary for further usage like this, especially for(item_detail,maintance,item_good,item_env):

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60de048cd7905488bbe0e511"
  },
  "item_name": "STOCKHOLM",
  "item_type": "Sofa",
  "item_id": "302.450.44",
  "item_detail": {
    "3paxsofa",
    "seglora"
  },
  "item_price": "18990",
  "item_count": "35",
  "item_size": {
    "width:": "211 cm",
    "depth:": "88 cm",
    "height:": "80 cm",
    "heigth2:": "14 cm",
    "height3:": "72 cm",
    "depth2:": "158 cm",
    "depth3:": "59 cm",
    "height4:": "43 cm",
    "no:": "3 "
  },
  "item_collapsepk": {
    "product_id: ": "302.450.44",
    "pack: ": "1",
    "depth: ": "216 cm",
    "width: ": "92 cm",
    "height: ": "60 cm",
    "total_weight: ": "71.26 kg",
    "net_weight: ": "56.64 kg",
    "pack_per: ": "1176.0 L"
  },
  "maintenance": {
    "avoid sunset ",
    "clear with wet towel"
  },
  "item_good": {
    "natural leather ",
    "softer leathwe ",
    "depper color and longer lifespan",
    "Niels Gammelgaard"
  },
  "item_env": {}
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60de048fd7905488bbe0e513"
  },
  "item_name": "HEMLINGBY",
  "item_type": "sofa",
  "item_id": "704.343.68",
  "item_detail": {
    "2pax sofa",
    "knisa"
  },
  "item_price": "899",
  "item_count": "2627",
  "item_size": {
    "width:": "145 cm",
    "depth:": "71.5 cm",
    "height:": "71.5 cm",
    "heigth2:": "14.5 cm",
    "height3:": "61 cm",
    "depth2:": "137 cm",
    "depth3:": "54 cm",
    "height4:": "42 cm"
  },
  "item_collapsepk": {
    "product_id: ": "704.343.68",
    "pack: ": "1",
    "depth: ": "137 cm",
    "width: ": "73 cm",
    "height: ": "32 cm",
    "total_weight: ": "34.32 kg",
    "net_weight: ": "29.86 kg",
    "pack_per: ": "320.0 L"
  },
  "maintenance": {
    "no bleach",
    "no dry"
  },
  "item_good": {
    "fixed"
  },
  "item_env": {}
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60de15b556f3d120e64db051"
  },
  "item_name": "ANGERSBY",
  "item_type": "梳化",
  "item_id": "804.571.18",
  "item_detail": {
    "2paxsofa",
    "knisa "
  },
  "item_price": "1690",
  "item_count": "842",
  "item_size": {
    "width:": "137 cm",
    "depth:": "84 cm",
    "width1:": "120 cm",
    "depth2:": "49 cm",
    "heigth2:": "46 cm"
  },
  "item_collapsepk": {
    "product_id: ": "804.571.18",
    "pack: ": "1",
    "depth: ": "87 cm",
    "width: ": "62 cm",
    "height: ": "47 cm",
    "total_weight: ": "28.00 kg",
    "net_weight: ": "26.28 kg",
    "pack_per: ": "253.5 L"
  },
  "maintenance": {
    "no bleach",
    "no dry",
    "咕套",
    "fixed",
    "40 degree with noral mode"
  },
  "item_good": null,
  "item_env": {
    "loner lifespan",
    "60%polyester",
    "40%rubber"
  }
 }
]
```

and the naming can be item_detail1, item_detail2, maintance1, maintance2 etc.
I try change the data structure in the python but I fail to get my expected result. How can get this result?

Comment: Those are not dictionaries: `"maintenance": {"no bleach","no dry"}`. Dictionaries have keys and values.

Comment: Oh, Then can I know what is it and how can I change to "maintenance": {"maintance1":"no bleach","maintance2":"no dry"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine if it's a list or a dict, then create a new dict using the list

```
import json


def json_to_dict(obj, key):
    _dict = {}        
    if type(obj) is dict:
        for key in obj.keys():
            _dict[key] = json_to_dict(obj[key], key)
        return _dict
    if type(obj) is list:
        for idx, child_obj in enumerate(obj):
            _dict[f"{key}{idx}"] = json_to_dict(child_obj, key)
        return _dict
    return obj

with open('product.json', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read()
    products = []
    for idx, product in enumerate(json.loads(read_data)):
        products.append(json_to_dict(product, idx))


    print(json.dumps(products, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        
f.closed
```

Comment: Thank You for your help! but how can I save it to the json file with correct format?